# How to rotate screen with the `var shouldAutorotate` returns false

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, screen, shouldautorotate

How to set the specified page rotation without having it rotate automatically? I found that the screen can rotate only when `var shouldAutorotate` returns yes, but I don't want to do that automatically,I want to control the moment of rotate by myself

Comment: I set VC's static variable ‘canRotate’, set it to true when it needs to be rotated, and set it to fals after the rotation is complete.   `override  var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return canRotate
    }`

Comment: the `canRotate` is seted false after received the UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, and I found that the screen can't rotate sometime in iphoneX, iOS 12.1 when  `orientationDidChangeNotification` comes (Although this is a small probability event)

Comment: the rotate screen code: ```UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")```

Comment: I resolved it use this before rotate code:  ```if !UIDevice.current.isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications {
            UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        }```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4+:

Use following code to rotate screen when required without any auto rotation as you want.

```
func rotateToLandscapeRight() {               
   UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

func rotateToLandscapeLeft() {
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

func rotateToPortratit() {                
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}
```